# Share handlebars template between modules (path issue)?

Tags: path, handlebars.js

I need to share Handlebars templates between modules, how can I point to a template in another modules folder (I've tried ALL variations of ../ * 1.000.000)?

```
    <div class="module-one-container">
        {{> ../../path/to/template/in/other-module/templates/folder/my_template)}}
    </div>
```

Comment: How are you registering your partials?

Comment: Yeah, turns out this is not the way Handlebars works at all ; ). I precompile them, and they are therefore accessible directly, as long as you remember that partials have to begin with an underscore ... I was simply trying to access an actual template and not a partial. Problem solved.